# Authorization error when accessing an aspx page

Tags: publishing-site, 403

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + IIS 6.0.

I have put a simple aspx page into layout folder (the code is very simple, just redirect to another page, and I write inline script code in asp.net), here is my code, and I met with unauthorized error (403) when I select to browse the page from IIS 6.0 manager.

I am not in Active Directory or Windows domain environment. I have enabled permission to anonymous users for the whole SharePoint site. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a permissions thing on the file system as a result of moving the file from some other location, which might have moved the original Access Control List along with that.

Try this:

1. open notepad
2. paste page contents into notepad
3. save in layouts as a .aspx file

Comment: I'll second that, except its probably a MOVE not a COPY. When you move files in NTFS the rights move with them (classic deployment error that will tear down your entire site if you do it with the wrong XSLT file for example ;-)
Another thing: consider doing code in codebehind instead of inline code. The safe mode parser in sharepoint allows inline code in application pages, but anywhere else its prohibited. Check out this article from AC: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx

Comment: Have updated my answer

Comment: I want to check by default, to access aspx pages by anonymous users in layout folder, there should not be any authorization issues?

Comment: I believe this is true, assuming your site is set to allow anonymous access AND you do not have any file system access issues. Did the suggested steps solve your problem?